# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 129.172.174.102:50491

Tags: c#, json, proxy, asp.net-mvc-5, httpcontext

I have used json code to call the controller/action method and convert the json format inside the project,everything worked in my localhost and my server which i had, but it was not working in some other server like US server, I don't know why it throws.

Is it cause Network or IIS confirguration or code issue? If Firewall or port issue means how to change their settings?

I have attached the code which I tried,

Class :

```
public class Jsonget
{
    public static string jsonconvert(string url)
    {
        string currentsite = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority;
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        wc.Encoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
        var uri = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
        var requestType = uri.Scheme;
        string jsonurl = requestType + "://" + currentsite + url;
        var jsondata = wc.DownloadString(jsonurl);
        string jsonresult = "{\"results\":" + jsondata.ToString() + "}";
        return jsonresult;
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
 jsonurl = Url.Action("GetallPrograms", "Admin", new { Name = "testprogram" });     
 getjsonresult = Jsonget.jsonconvert(jsonurl);
 Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject programList = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(getjsonresult);
 foreach (var pgm in programList["results"])
 {
   <p>@((string)pgm["ProgramName"])</p>
 }
```

AdminController:

```
public JsonResult GetallPrograms(string Name)
{
    var programList = new List<CustomAttribute>();
    BaseController bc = new BaseController();
    try
    {
        var Exist_programs = (from n in bc.db.Programs where n.Name == Name select n).ToList();                          
        foreach (var exist in Exist_programs)
        {
           programList.Add(new CustomAttribute
           {
              ProgramName = exist.ProgramName,
              Id = exist.Id.ToString()
            });
         } 
     }
    catch
    {
       programList.Add(new CustomAttribute
       {
          ProgramName ="",
          Id = ""
        });
     }
     return Json(programList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

Please give suggestion to fix this?

Comment: is the IP ping?

Comment: The localhost IP is 127.0.0.1. Can you ping it on 129.0.0.1?

Comment: AFAIK 129.0.0.1 isn't a [reserved range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses) - it *could* be the correct address, but it sounds a *lot* like a typo...

Comment: What is the network IP of the server, where you want to connect with WebClient? Where do you want to connect, when the connection failed?

Comment: i just mentioned ip address and port which were coming on clientside

Comment: The 129.0.0.1 is the local IP of the server. Your localhost and server is in the same local network so you can use this IP to connect. But if you want to call your server from outer network, you can not use this 192.0.0.1 from outer network.

Comment: i did not added any ip address and port in the code

Comment: What url do you use?

Comment: Confused, what's the purpose of `Jsonget` in the first place? Unless I'm missing it, you're calling your _own_ endpoint(?).

Comment: am just calling action in the view and bind the jsondata into html data, or give me alternative solution how to call action method in the viewpage and bind the data. But why it was not working in their end?